# how to get the job id from qsub

Tags: cluster-computing, pbs, qsub

I am using a cluster. I will use qsub command to distribute my job, what I want is I can get back the job id so that I can monitor the job.

Basically, I want some thing like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
JOBID=$( qsub job1 )
# Monitoring base on $JOBID
```

I found a page http://wiki.ibest.uidaho.edu/index.php/Tutorial:_Submitting_a_job_using_qsub, and it talks about a variable `PBS_JOBID` but I don't know how to use it. Does anyone know how to do it?

(My solution now is `jobID='qsub task | cut -d ' ' -f 3'`)

Comment: I believe there are serveral different batch systems that use a command called `qsub`. I've add the "pbs" tag to indicate which one you're asking about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`qsub` has a very predictable output.  Many automated submission systems (such as Grid interfaces) simply parse the output from `qsub`, looking for the jobid.

An example of parsing is available from the BLAHP project (European grid middleware).

```
jobID=`${pbs_binpath}/qsub $bls_tmp_file` # actual submission
...

# The job id is actually the first numbers in the string (slurm support)
jobID=`echo $jobID | awk 'match($0,/[0-9]+/){print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)}'`
```

([source](https://github.com/osg-bosco/BLAH/blob/1d217fad9c6b54a5e543f7a9d050e77047be0bb1/src/scripts/pbs_submit.sh#L193))

This code has been used in production for many years, and has worked for `qsub` in both PBS, PBS Pro, and SLURM.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `-terse`:

```
$ echo sleep 5 | qsub -terse
3543
```